# Proper way to release objects in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

If I have an object Sale that contains another object Item.  Let's say my Sale header looks like this:

```
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import "Item.h"

    @interface Sale : NSObject {
        Item *item;
    }

    @property (readonly) Item *item;

    -(id) initWithItem:(Item*)i;

    @end
```

And in my function I create a new Item and Sale object like so:

```
    Item *i = [[Item alloc] init];
    Sale *s = [[Sale alloc] initWithItem:i];
    [i release];
```

If, when I'm done with the Sale object I simply do:

```
    [s release];
```

is that enough to make sure that all of that memory allocation is cleaned up effectively?

Furthermore, will releasing *i cause any issues if I later try to access [s item]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you're storing `i`. If you copy or retain it in `initWithItem:`, you need to release it in `Sale`'s `dealloc` method (see below). If you're storing a weak reference, this is fine.

```
- (id)initWithItem:(Item *)i {
  if ((self = [super init])) {
    // If you're retaining i here, you need to release it in dealloc.
    item = [i retain];
  }

  return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
  [item release];
  [super dealloc];
}
```

See Apple's [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html) for more information.

Comment: How about if I am just assigning i like this?:
item = i;

Comment: @link664 In that case, you are storing a weak reference: `s` does not own `i`, it simply has a reference to it. Thus, if you release `i` outside of `s` (as in your example) you will encounter problems if you attempt to access `[s item]`. I would recommend you copy/retain `i` in your initialiser and release it in `dealloc`.